# jQuery: For each attribute of an input element how do I get that input element's name?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm looking at each input element that has an attribute named "isDate".  I want to find that attributes parent input element's name attribute.

```
<input name="A0000" isDate="true" value="01/01/2020" />
<input name="A0001" isDate="true" value="01/01/2021" />
<input name="A0002" isDate="true" value="01/01/2022" />
<input name="A0003" isDate="true" value="01/01/2023" />
<input name="A0004" isDate="true" value="01/01/2024" />
<input name="A0005" isDate="true" value="01/01/2025" />


  $("input[isDate="true"]).each(function(){
     var _this = this;
// do stuff then... 

// get name of input
     var name =  $(_this).parent().attr("name").val(); // this doesn't work
  });
```

Comment: `var name =  $(_this).parent().attr("name");` should work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`this` will reference the element, not the attribute, so you won't need `.parent()`

```
$("input[isDate='true']").each(function(){
    // get name of input
    var name =  $(this).attr("name");
});
```

I also fixed some of your syntax too!

Comment: I'm trying to get the name attribute from the point of retrieving the isDate attribute.  Any suggestions? thx

Comment: Sorry, "from the point of retrieving the isDate attribute"? I don't understand...

Comment: Your right.  I thought I was referencing the attribute with the "this" statement.  Ok thx!

Answer (score 1):

Skip the parent and val part

See [here](http://jsfiddle.net/AkqJU/)

Answer (score 1):

Check out the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/SEsBH/

```
  $('input[isDate="true"]').each(function(){
     var _this = this;
// do stuff then... 

// get name of input
     console.log($(this).attr('name'));
  });
```

You have a wrong `"` in `$("input[isDate`. And one missing :)

Also you can just reference the current element using `$(this)`

Comment: Yeah, whoops I wrote it freehand without the IDE so go figure. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you were looking for?

```
<input name="A0000" isDate="true" value="01/01/2020" />
<input name="A0001" isDate="true" value="01/01/2021" />
<input name="A0002" isDate="true" value="01/01/2022" />
<input name="A0003" isDate="true" value="01/01/2023" />
<input name="A0004" isDate="true" value="01/01/2024" />
<input name="A0005" isDate="true" value="01/01/2025" />


$("input[isDate="true"]).each(function(){
    var _this = this;
    // do stuff then... 

    // get name of input
    var name =  _this.name;
});
```

Good luck!